# es6 implement polymorphism with extend

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6, polymorphism

look the code below. The `A` extend `B` and let `B` call sub-class's function to implement polymorphism. But if I want add a parameter to `B`,since the `super()` must be call before use `this.param = param`,so I can not via that way to pass parame to  `B`'s `polymorphism()`. So how to make the `B`'s `polymorphism()` to use my custom param which pass via `B`'s constructor? Is there a way make the `B`'s constructor can be add a parameter which use to do some custom business?

```
class A{
    constructor()
    {
        this.polymorphism();
    }
    polymorphism(){
        console.log("A")
    }
}
class B extends A{
    constructor(param)
    {
        super();
    }
    polymorphism()
    {
        console.log("B")
        /**use param
         * business code**/
    }
}
new B()
```

Comment: `if I want add a parameter to B` you did, it's called param, you can then do, this.param = param in constructor to "save" it in the object

Comment: The `super()` must be call before use this.So when the `A` call `this.polymorphism()` there no custom param yet

Comment: ahh, yes, that is a conundrum

Comment: The answer to your question is essentially "you can't". If you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve with this polymorphic behavior, we could make try to make recommendations though. Also note that this is an issue that arises in many languages and is general a code smell. A constructors job should generally be simple construction, and this pattern usually only arises if you're trying to do a lot more.

Comment: You mean that:
`constructor(a,b)
    {
        this.a= a;
        this.b= b;
    }`?
The constructor just set the sub-class's variable,and the business code should be cover in another specific function? Does that is a typically implement way?